# Spark SQL doesn't see hdfs files

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I have a spark application, which running on cluster AWS EMR.

I've added file to hdfs:

```
javaSparkContext.addFile(filePath, recursive);
```

File exist on hdfs (logs available: file is readable/executeble/writable), but I can't read information from this file using spark SQL API:

```
 LOGGER.info("Spark working directory: " + path);
 File file = new File(path + "/test.avro");
 LOGGER.info("SPARK PATH:" + file);
 LOGGER.info("read:" + file.canRead());
 LOGGER.info("execute:" + file.canExecute());
 LOGGER.info("write:" + file.canWrite());
 Dataset<Row> load = getSparkSession()
                      .read()
                      .format(AVRO_DATA_BRICKS_LIBRARY)
                      .load(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

There is logs:

```
17/08/07 15:03:25 INFO SparkContext: Added file /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1502118042722_0001/container_1502118042722_0001_01_000001/test.avro at spark://HOST:PORT/files/test.avro with timestamp 1502118205059
17/08/07 15:03:25 INFO Utils: Copying /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1502118042722_0001/container_1502118042722_0001_01_000001/test.avro to /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1502118042722_0001/spark-d5b494fc-2613-426f-80fc-ca66279c2194/userFiles-44aad2e8-04f4-420b-9b5e-a1ccde5db9ec/test.avro
17/08/07 15:03:25 INFO AbstractS3Calculator: Spark working directory: /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1502118042722_0001/spark-d5b494fc-2613-426f-80fc-ca66279c2194/userFiles-44aad2e8-04f4-420b-9b5e-a1ccde5db9ec
17/08/07 15:03:25 INFO AbstractS3Calculator: SPARK PATH:/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1502118042722_0001/spark-d5b494fc-2613-426f-80fc-ca66279c2194/userFiles-44aad2e8-04f4-420b-9b5e-a1ccde5db9ec/test.avro
17/08/07 15:03:25 INFO AbstractS3Calculator: read:true
17/08/07 15:03:25 INFO AbstractS3Calculator: execute:true
17/08/07 15:03:25 INFO AbstractS3Calculator: write:true

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: hdfs://HOST:PORT/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1502118042722_0001/spark-d5b494fc-2613-426f-80fc-ca66279c2194/userFiles-44aad2e8-04f4-420b-9b5e-a1ccde5db9ec/test.avro;
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:135)
    at odh.spark.services.algorithms.calculators.RiskEngineS3Calculator.getInputMembers(RiskEngineS3Calculator.java:76)
    at odh.spark.services.algorithms.calculators.RiskEngineS3Calculator.getMembersDataSets(RiskEngineS3Calculator.java:124)
    at odh.spark.services.algorithms.calculators.AbstractS3Calculator.calculate(AbstractS3Calculator.java:50)
    at odh.spark.services.ProgressSupport.start(ProgressSupport.java:47)
    at odh.spark.services.Engine.startCalculations(Engine.java:102)
    at odh.spark.services.Engine.startCalculations(Engine.java:135)
    at odh.spark.SparkApplication.main(SparkApplication.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:637)
```

Comment: can you show the value of path ?

Comment: Path is Spark working directory in log

Comment: Try running application as root.

Comment: I've added permission (777) for all users. It doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

check if do you have that file in your `hdfs`:

`hadoop fs -ls /home/spark/`# or your working directory instead of /home/spark

If you have that file on hdfs, it looks like [the problem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15899) on side of Spark, just follow to instruction in descriptions or update your `Spark` version to the latest

Answer (score 0):

By default all files stores in `/user/hadoop/` folder in HDFS. (you can use this knowledge and load with this **constant**, but better - need to use absolute paths)

To upload to HDFS and use this files - I've used absolute paths:

```
new Configuration().get("fs.defaultFS")//get HDFS root
....
 FileSystem hdfs = getHdfsFileSystem();
 hdfs.copyFromLocalFile(true, true, new Path(srcLocalPath), new Path(destHdfsPath));
```

Where `destHdfsPath` - absolute path ( like `'hdfs://...../test.avro'` )

And then you available to load this information from HDFS:

```
return getSparkSession()
                .read()
                .format(AVRO_DATA_BRICKS_LIBRARY)
                .load(absoluteFilePath);
```

**NOTE**: meybe need to add some permissions: `FileUtil.chmod(hdfsDest, "u+rw,g+rw,o+rw");`